# "Богове", "синове" як називний відмінок множини. Що за форма?

Tags: кличний-відмінок, керування-відмінками, число

Гомер. Іліада. Переклад Бориса Тена - Борис Тен (переклад з давньогрецької), 1978 - Харків: Фоліо, 2006. - 416 с.:

> 290] Хай списоборцем його вічносущі **богове** створили,
>
> 291] Та чи на те, щоб усіх він поганими лаяв словами?»

Потім:

> 281] Щоб у перших рядах і в останніх **синове** ахеїв
>
> 282] Слово розчути могли і слушну пораду збагнути.

Спробував декілька запитів у ґуґлі, але не можу знайти нічого притомного.

Можете, будь ласка, пояснити, що це за така форма називного відмінку у множині, яка виглядає як кличний?

Comment: [Коментар у Фейсбуці](//www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1421430154649693&id=811367038989344&comment_id=1421497334642975) від Marina Titova: «Знаю, що в польській мові в називному множини так відмінюється деякі слова, що означають поважних осіб (_ojcowie_, _bogowie_, _profesorowie_)».

Comment: Колись слухав лекцію про класичну китайську поезію, там лектор зауважив, що для перекладу Гомера російською фактично довелося вигадати спеціальну мову щоб адекватно передати оригінал. Можливо Борис Тен також пішов шляхом введення в українську мову конструкцій, яких немає в літературній мові для того щоб передати особливості Іліади.

Comment: До речі, у колядці "[Бог ся рождає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D1%81%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%94)" теж схожа форма використовується: "Пастиріє клячуть, В плоті Бога бачуть", "А пастиріє к Ньому прибігають, І яко царя свойого вітають."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Наші іменники, створені волею Зевса і Гери,

Різними суфіксами прикрашає народ працелюбний;

Ніби віночок вдягає на слово, щоб слово блищало,

Навіть щоб боги побачили ті, що живуть на Говерлі.*

*Йменники, що позначають слова чоловічого роду,

У множині що знаходяться і в називному відмінку,

Можуть отримувать суфікси `-ов-`, зокрема, в діалектах —

Як-то: "сино́ве, брато́ве, пано́ве, кумо́ве, свато́ве".*

*Цей феномен є відомим у славній еллінській науці;

Він, зокрема, розглядався Степаном Бевзенком,

Що проспівав у своїй видатній науковій роботі* <sup>**(1)**</sup>
*Славу і честь і потужну осанну цьому феномену:*

> **Множина**
>
> Із діалектних форм наз. відм. множини вкажемо на поширені, хоч і обмежено, в карпатських і в ряді інших південно-західних говорів форми іменників чоловічого роду **з флексією `-ове`, перенесеної з колишніх `-й-` основ**: *сино́ве, брато́ве, пано́ве, кумо́ве, свато́ве, сус'ідове* та ін.; *вірло́ве*
> (орли), *вітро́ве, дошчо́ве* та ін.

---

<sup>**(1)**</sup> Бевзенко С.П. **«Українська діалектологія»** (стор. 102)

- [переглянути (DocSlide)](https://documents.tips/documents/-55721248497959fc0b905bb1.html)
- [скачувати (PDF)](https://studfiles.net/preview/5550387/)

Answer (score 4):

На подібну форму можна натрапити в Шевченка ("І Архімед, і Галілей..."):

А люде виростуть. Умруть

Ще незачатиє царята...

І на оновленій землі

Врага не буде, супостата,

А буде син, і буде мати,

І будуть люде на землі.

А також у Словникові Грінченка:

> **Лю́де**, -де́й, мн. ([звідси](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5))
>
> 1) Люди. Бог Богом, а люде людьми. Ном. № 170. Бог судить не так, як люде. Ном. № 34. От уже й люде трапляються, — от уже й заміж пора — Які там, мамо, люде? — Харько Кабиця. О. 1861. XI. Кух. 13. з його люде будуть. Изъ него толкъ будетъ. Ном. № 4866. Я тоді ще бачив, які з його люде будуть. вас за людей мають. Васъ считаютъ за людей, къ вамъ относятся какъ къ людямъ. в людях. Публично, при народѣ. Шануй одежу в дворі, вона тебе в людях. Ном. № 11128.
>
> 2) Простой народъ. Дивись! пан, а балака, як люде. Ном. № 1244. Чи пани, чи люде? Ном. № 1138. То пани, а ми люде. Ном. № 1139. Ум. людки́. (Чуб. III. 109), людоньки, людочки. Людоньки! та де в мене гроші взялися? Камен. у. Людочки! як же я злякалась! Ув. людиська, люди́ща. Єсть люде, єсть і людиська (людища). Ном. № 2450.
>
> <sub>Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 2. — С. 388.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Не маю часу належно оформити відповідь. Але знайшов посилання на панове, кумове, братове в українського класика Б.Лепкого. По суті, це кличний відмінок множини. Ось [обговорення панове та решти слів](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2374.html). Читайте останній допис на тій сторінці. Наведені приклади у тому дописі також свідчать про називний відмінок, який там названий номінативною формою. Тобто це не винахід Тена.

Comment: але у Бориса Тена це не кличний, а називний відмінок.